# Pagination in Firebase realtime database

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database, pagination

I am using Firebase realtime database and quite new to NoSQL.Here is an example of my database structure.

[image: Sample database Json tree]

I want to get all seasons out through a REST GET method. something like below code segment.

```
 @GetMapping(value = "seasons", params = {"page", "size"})
    public ResponseEntity<List<SeasonDTO>> getAllSeasons(@RequestParam("page") int page, @RequestParam("size") int size) {
        ResponseEntity<List<FSeason>> fSeasons = DBHandle.retrieveDataList(FSeason.class, dbRef.child(FSeason.key).orderByKey().limitToFirst(page * size).limitToLast((page + 1) * size));
       ........
        List<SeasonDTO> map = modelMapper.map(fSeasons.getBody(), seasonDTOListType);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(map, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

I tried implementing database Query like:

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance(firebaseApp).getReference("resources").child(FSeason.key).orderByKey().limitToFirst(page * size).limitToLast((page + 1) * size)
```

but failed. Can someone show me how Query should be written properly.

Comment: I think that this [resource](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-implement-pagination-in-realtime-database-using-jetpack-compose-bd49084c8fd4) will help. Here is the corresponding [repo](https://github.com/alexmamo/RealtimeDatabasePaginationJetpackCompose).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance(firebaseApp)
    .getReference("resources")
    .child(FSeason.key)
    .orderByKey()
    .startAt(id)
    .limit(size)
```

Here, `startAt(...)` will set the cursor in your database. The order of these data is defined by your `orderByKey()` function which orders your data alphabetically. Moreover, the `limit(...)` function defines how many data to retrieve per query.

Here's the official documentation on **startAt(...)**:

> Create a query constrained to only return child nodes with a value
>   greater than or equal to the given value, using the given orderBy
>   directive or priority as default.

The `id` in `startAt(id)` represents the id of the last retrieved document. So, every time you parse the results from your query, store the last element's id and use that for the next query.

Comment: does not using orderbykey will download nodes to client and then do pagination at client side, then it will not beneficial.

Comment: what if the key is an integer in firebase database? I see there is no way to order by an integer key

Comment: "The id of the last retrieved document" doesn't quite work, because documents are returned as a JSON object not an array, so there is no "last" one because there's no ordering. Are we really supposed to alphabetically order all keys ourselves? I'd be concerned that a slight deviation in my ordering vs Firebase's ordering could cause an infinite loop.