# Firebase Realtime Database: how to get subset data by using query?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-cloud-platform, firebase-realtime-database

Here's my data structure, using timestamp as ID:

```
{
    "posts": {
        "1703921218409": {
            "category": "All",
            "content": "1",
            "title": "1"
        },
        "1703921229327": {
            "category": "All",
            "content": "2",
            "title": "2"
        },
        "1703921232777": {
            "category": "All",
            "content": "3",
            "title": "3"
        },
        "1703921236094": {
            "category": "All",
            "content": "4",
            "title": "4"
        },
        "1703921239468": {
            "category": "All",
            "content": "5",
            "title": "5"
        },
        "1703921243055": {
            "category": "All",
            "content": "6",
            "title": "6"
        },
        "1703921246316": {
            "category": "All",
            "content": "7",
            "title": "7"
        }
    }
```

I want to build a forum in reactjs and show 5 post in one page, so it work like:
page1 (post 1-5), page2 (post 6-10), ...etc

The problem is I dont know how to get post 6-10 directly, all I can do is get post 1-10 from firebase and filter post 6-10 in client side.

```
      const snapshot = await get( query(ref(db, 'posts'), limitToLast(10)) )
      // do a iteration to get needed data (post 6-10)
```

But if user go to page 1000, I need to fetch post 1-5000 and discard post 1-4995 just for the last 5 post, it seems inefficient.

So is there any way to get the subset data directly instead of getting the whole data and filtering it out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want to build a forum in reactjs and show 5 post in one page, so it work like: page1 (post 1-5), page2 (post 6-10), ...etc

What you're looking for is called pagination. This means you'll have to load the data in smaller chunks. When it comes to the Realtime Database, as far as I know, there is no official example of how to implement it. This topic has been covered before, so please check the below approach:

- [Pagination in Firebase realtime database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59430023/pagination-in-firebase-realtime-database)

If you however consider at some point in time trying to use [Cloud Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/), I can tell you that there is a very simple way to implement pagination which is by using [query cursors](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/query-cursors). Maybe you should give it a try.

Comment: I did not notice that firestroe is difference from realtime database and the former one is recommented to new developer. I will give it a try now, thanks!